# Grails 2.4 transitive plugin dependencies don't respect the 'exclude' directive

Tags: maven, grails

We're currently developing a Grails plugin that is meant to be a shared library of goodies for several different applications.  This plug-in does the management around GORM and caching and, as such, it includes both the hibernate plug-in and the cache and cache-ehcache plugins.  Hibernate and cache-ehcache plug-ins both want to import the ehcache-core jar dependency, but with different versions.  The version of ehcache-core that I want is the one in the cache-ehcache plug-in so I've configured my BuildConfig.groovy like so:

```
compile(':hibernate:3.6.10.10', { excludes 'ehcache-core' })
compile ':cache:1.1.8'
compile ":cache-ehcache:1.0.4"
```

When running tests in this plug-in everything works just fine.  However, once I include this plug-in in one of my real applications the excludes directive seems to be ignored and the transitive dependency on the hibernate plug-in starts pulling in ehcache-core.  Having two versions of ehcache-core breaks many different aspects.

I've checked the grails dependency-report for my applications and it shows the chain of dependencies from my app -> my utility plugin -> hibernate plugin -> ehcache-core intact.  The same dependency report run on the plug-in itself just points to the hibernate plug-in and then stops with no dependency on ehcache-core.

Anyone out there have any ideas as to why the dependency exclusion works while running the plug-in, but not while running the application that depends on the plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the change to the Maven/Aether dependency manager library. It's somewhat less buggy than Ivy and significantly faster, but is missing a lot of features that many of us are used to. One easy fix is to switch back to the Ivy resolver. You would only need to do that for the plugings when publishing, but not necessarily when using them since you need a defailed .pom file with exclusions listed so the consuming dependency manager knows what to ignore. If you use Aether the .pom files only include dependencies.

EDIT: I was focusing on the correctness of the pom files, and or course exclusions like this should work (although it'd be better  to have correct poms and not have to force every user to fix this on their end.)

The issue might be that your group or name are different (e.g, "cache" vs. "ehcache"), and then they cant evict/exclude another. Or the jar might be coming from a different dependency and they exclusions are not global. There may be a way to set a global exclusion, but I don't know of one and there's nothing in the docs.